# Find who triggered Azure Data Factory pipeline - ADF

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

How can one find who triggered the ADF pipeline from the Monitor page?

It does say Manual trigger when a user triggers it but not specifically who the user is.

[image]

Is there a way to get the logged in user's email or name?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can simply find this using **Activity Log** like below.

[image]

Go to particular ADF Resource and Choose 'Activity Log' Blade. Then with the use of filters, you can narrow down the results an find the high level details like what operation name was done, when was done and by whom it was done.

If you need more details, you can use Azure Monitor[+Kusto Query language in Azure Log Analytics if Logging is enabled already]

Comment: Great! Thankyou!! Is there way to filter them by pipeline name rather than the operation name?

Comment: If we enable 'Logging' for our ADF Resources, then we do even more customization[pipeline level filters etc.,] in Log Analytics using KQL.